# How do you customize the dialogue that appears when asked for location?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I have submitted my app for review, but it got rejected for the following reason:

> Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the location, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location in the purpose string. To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, permission request alerts need to explain and include an example of how your app will use the requested information.

My App uses the `LocationButton` provided by apple for a one time use of their location. I have googled around and still haven't found anything. I have added all of the info.plist blocks under "Privacy-Location" but still nothing.

[image: info.plist file]

[image: the app]

Location Button:

```swift
final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40, longitude: 120), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 100, longitudeDelta: 100))
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestAllowOnceLocationPermission() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else {
            // show an error
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: latestLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You stated: *I have added all of the info.plist blocks under Privacy-Location*. Apple's rejection stated: *but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location in the purpose string*. Make sure the strings you enter for the Info.plist Privacy strings tell the user why your app needs the privacy setting. The strings you show in your question are useless and why your app is being rejected.

Comment: Where is the purpose string? Do I have to create it? I will add the location button code

Comment: You show that for the "Privacy - Location When In Use" string you entered "polygon 1111". That's useless. You need to enter a useful sentence that the user will read to understand why your app needs to access the their location when in use. Same for the others. None of this has anything to do with your code.

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I put that there as a placeholder until i figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way you can call custom requests for permissions. At most, you can edit messages for which you need this or that permission. Logically, if your employer still asks you to make it more beautiful, you can write a separate screen for access for all permissions in your app.